# Laden with and loaded with

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the meaning of following two sentences?

> The ship was **loaded with/laden with** cotton?

Is anyone grammatically wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`Laden` is perhaps more technical, certainly more archaic (though still in regular use), but otherwise `Laden` and `Loaded` are pretty much identical in this use.